# sorting list of dataframes by date

Tags: r, date, dplyr, reorderlist

I have a list of dataframes in a structure similar to this:

```
`ID1_01/05/10` <- data.frame(c(1,1))
`ID1_21/02/10` <- data.frame(c(2,1))
`ID2_01/05/10` <- data.frame(c(3,1))
`ID2_21/02/10` <- data.frame(c(4,1))
lst <- list(mget ( ls ( pattern = 'ID\\d+')))
```

I'd like to order them in the list first by identity and then by date. I.e.:

```
`ID1_21/02/10`
`ID1_01/05/10`
`ID2_21/02/10`
`ID2_01/05/10`
```

Is there a way of doing this easily?

Comment: I think you don't need to wrap around `mget` as it is already a `list`.  Now, this becomes a `list` of `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We extract the `names`, get the numeric part ('v1') and the `Date` part, and `order` based on it

```
nm1 <-  sapply(lst, names)[,1]
v1 <- as.numeric(sub(".*(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", nm1))
d1 <- as.Date(sub(".*_", "", nm1), "%d/%m/%y")
nm1[order(v1, d1)]
#[1] "ID1_21/02/10" "ID1_01/05/10" "ID2_21/02/10" "ID2_01/05/10"

lapply(lst, function(x) x[order(v1, d1)])
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$`ID1_21/02/10`
# c.2..1.
#1       2
#2       1

#[[1]]$`ID1_01/05/10`
#  c.1..1.
#1       1
#2       1

#[[1]]$`ID2_21/02/10`
#  c.4..1.
#1       4
#2       1

#[[1]]$`ID2_01/05/10`
#  c.3..1.
#1       3
#2       1
```

#### Update

In the OP's example, the `mget` was wrapped with `list` and it would create a `list` of `lists`.  Instead it would be

```
lst <- mget ( ls ( pattern = 'ID\\d+'))
```

and if that is the case, then

```
nm1 <- names(lst)
lst[order(v1, d1)]
```